# Does Azure deallocate end user's VM's at its own discretion?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Does Azure deallocate end user's VM's at its own discretion?

I was using an Azure VM for a clean build and then the remote connection was dropped, I tried to reconnect by RDP and found out the machine was deallocated.
The info from Microsoft was:

Connect is disabled because this virtual machine is deallocated.

I did not know that Azure took machines away like that?
I would be hesitant to use Azure VM's in the future for build work.

Comment: Azure does *not* just deallocate VMs on its own - this has to be a deliberate action (unless you're on some type of trial subscription with limited resources). Also, your VM is probably still there, but in a stopped (non-billed) state, which you can then restart. All that aside: this type of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's not programming-related. Perhaps a better fit on SuperUser, but you'd need to provide more details (vm log, etc).

Comment: It was terminated, it was an MSDN account that had $148 in it.  VM was terminated and I lost work and was not able to restart it.

Comment: happened to me today

Comment: Azure activity log says "Event initiated by Azure Lab Services"

Answer (score 2):

Azure does not de-allocate your VM.  There are numerous reasons you VM might be de-allocated while you are using it, below are a few;

- Like @david mentioned in comment, you ran out of credit
- Shared subscription, someone that also has access to you subscription shutdown VM
- Automation, VM is set to shutdown at a certain time

These a just a few reason why you vm might have de-allocated while you are using it.  If you can't determine on your own why it shutdown you can file a support ticket with Azure support.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe Microsoft made a decision to terminate the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your appropriate resource group is enabled:

1. Open Azure portal.
2. Navigate to the Subscriptions.
3. Search for the necessary subscription group. enable it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is a scheduled shutdown on `Azure`. If you go to operations settings in the left panel of the `Azure VM` portal, there is an auto-shutdown. You need to disable it so that your `VM` won't shutdown at the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

Azure VM machine might be in stopped mode so it is saying that error message, please check the Azure VM list and see the status, accordingly start the VM, it will work

Answer (score 0):

normally when you create your VM, you will see that there is a parameter that it will stop at 7pm or something like that. So After 7pm it will stop you VM. Which is good I think, because we tend to forget our VMs and then we pay for nothing. So no worries, just start your vm and you are all good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

When you created the resources this was one of the options to save money. You can simply go back into the resource Overview page. At the top of the section hit the Start (Play) button. Azure portal will then give you a notification that you rVM is starting with a little progress bar scrolling underneath the alerts. As soon as it has been reallocated it will be available to connect. I know this is an old thread but hope it helps someone in the future.